# Notification does not work in Presentviewcontroller objective-c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, notifications, presentviewcontroller

I am displaying a `UIAlertController` when I receive a response from API. After the response, I want to call the notification of other view controller.

I added observer in view controller 1 as below:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(UpdateAthleteDictionaryNotification:) name:@"UpdateAthleteDictionary" object:self.dictProfile];
```

In view controller 2 my code is below:

```
UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:applicationName
                                 message:[jsonObject valueForKey:@"responseMessage"]
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdateAthleteDictionary" object:self.dictProfile];
                                    });
                                    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                                }];
    [alert addAction:yesButton];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But it does not call. So please can you suggest me the solutions.

Comment: have you added remove observer code for your all notifications

Comment: No, If I remove then how it will call from another view?

Comment: This code works fine on my mac. Could you please provide the implementation of `UpdateAthleteDictionaryNotification`? How do you modify `self.dictProfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSNotificationCenter will deliver your notification only in case if name and object are the same ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter/1415360-addobserver?language=objc)).
If you want to receive notifications with any object attached you should pass nil as an object argument, in your case:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(UpdateAthleteDictionaryNotification:) name:@"UpdateAthleteDictionary" object:nil];
```